# Ключевые кадры в анимации

Tags: css3

Доброго времени суток.

Не могу вникнуть в ключевые кадры анимации, а точнее, например делаю слайдер, в нем 3 картинки, задаю анимации 15 секунд скорости, и infinite.
 
Теперь например хочу сделать что бы картинка стояла 3 секунды далее уходила влево за 2 сек. 
 И за ней сразу же шла вторая картинка, и она должна стоять 3 секунды, и уходить влево за 2 секунды, далее за ней третья картинка выдвигается и 3 сек стоит. И т.д. 
 Так вот, очень хочется понять эту тему, объясните пожалуйста подробней, как мне грамотно рассчитать ключевые кадры?

Сам я пытался сделать так:

```
0%{left: 0px;opacity: 1}
16%{left: 0px;opacity: 1}
25%{left: -680px; opacity: 0}
34%{left: -680px; opacity: 0}
43%{left: 680px;opacity: 0}
52%{left: 680px;opacity: 0}
61%{left: 0;opacity: 1}
70%{left: 0;opacity: 1}
79%{left: -680px;opacity: 0}
88%{left: 680px;opacity: 0}
97%{left: 680px;opacity: 0}
100%{left: 0px;opacity: 0}
```

Но на конечной точке, первая картинка не выдвигается плавно как до этого, а встает на первую точку резко.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Это решение для варианта, когда текущий слайд уезжает со следующего.

Если требуется просто сдвиг слайдов, то надо использовать другой способ.**

*Какова длительность всей анимации?*

(3 сек + 2 сек) * 5 шт = 25 сек.
1 сек = 4%.

*Как сделать анимацию каждой картинки?*

1. 3s картинка просто стоит:

   ```
    0% { left: 0; }
   12% { left: 0; }
   ```
2. 2s уезжает влево:

   ```
   18% { left: -100%; }
   ```
3. Потом незаметно возвращается обратно:

   ```
   18.001% { z-index: -1; left: -100%; }
   100%    { z-index: -1; left: 0; }
   ```

   Значения повторно использовать нельзя, поэтому добавляем отклонение на .001%.
4. Но надо, чтобы за 2 секунды до конца блок уже был видим, поэтому последнюю строку заменяем на:

   ```
    92% { z-index:  0; left: 0;     }
   100% { z-index:  0; left: 0;     }
   ```
5. Исправить косяк с анимацией `z-index` - не показывать элемент раньше чем нужно:

   ```
   91.999% { z-index: -1; left: 0;     }
   ```

*Как сделать анимацию слайдера?*

Использовать `animation-delay` для слайдов.

*Что Можно улучшить?*

Производительность за счёт использование transform:translate вместо left.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  animation: slide 25s linear infinite both;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0%     { z-index:  1; left: 0;     }
   12%     { z-index:  1; left: 0;     }
   18%     { z-index:  1; left: -100%; }
   18.001% { z-index: -1; left: -100%; }
   18.002% { z-index: -1; left: 0;     }
   91.999% { z-index: -1; left: 0;     }
   92%     { z-index:  0; left: 0;     }
  100%     { z-index:  0; left: 0;     }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div style="animation-delay:   0s; background: red;"></div>
  <div style="animation-delay: -20s; background: green;"></div>
  <div style="animation-delay: -15s; background: blue;"></div>
  <div style="animation-delay: -10s; background: silver;"></div>
  <div style="animation-delay:  -5s; background: antiquewhite;"></div>
</section>
```

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  height: 10em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  animation: slide 25s linear infinite both;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0%     { z-index:  1; transform: translateX(0);     }
   12%     { z-index:  1; transform: translateX(0);     }
   18%     { z-index:  1; transform: translateX(-100%); }
   18.001% { z-index: -1; transform: translateX(-100%); }
   18.002% { z-index: -1; transform: translateX(0);     }
   91.999% { z-index: -1; transform: translateX(0);     }
   92%     { z-index:  0; transform: translateX(0);     }
  100%     { z-index:  0; transform: translateX(0);     }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div style="animation-delay:   0s; background: red;"></div>
  <div style="animation-delay: -20s; background: green;"></div>
  <div style="animation-delay: -15s; background: blue;"></div>
  <div style="animation-delay: -10s; background: silver;"></div>
  <div style="animation-delay:  -5s; background: antiquewhite;"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Отлично, но пожалуйста разъясните мне, как вы расчитываете ключевые кадры? По какой формуле? Что на что делите умножаете? Вот мне интересно как вы высчитали вот эти ключевые кадры  0% 12% 18% и т.д.?

Comment: @Dolphin, в первом пункте же написано: 100% = 25 сек => 1 сек = 4%.

Comment: Исправил баг с `z-index`ом.

Comment: Да, Qwertiy, извините не заметил. А 1 сек = 4% это всегда или только на момент этих подсчетов (3 сек + 2 сек) * 5 шт = 25 сек. ?

Comment: Qwertiy, я наверное замучал вас своими вопросами, но мне очень хочется понять и научится. Если что за ранее, прошу прощения.

Comment: Qwertiy, например если длительность всей а нимации состовляет 15 сек, т.е.  (3 сек + 2 сек) * 3 шт = 15 сек.   (3шт изображений), то вэтом случае скольки % будет равна 1 секунда?

Comment: @Dolphin, 100 % разделить на 15 сек получается 6.666.

Comment: Qwertiy, огромное вам спасибо!!!

Comment: Qwertiy, вот теперь я понял, и смогу сам рачитывать каждый ключевой кадр. Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

*0% и 100% по сути совпадают. Лучше брать 4%, а не 0% или 0% и 96%.*

Например:

```css
div {  
  -webkit-animation: Anim 8s ease-in-out infinite;
          animation: Anim 8s ease-in-out infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes Anim {
  4%{left: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  16%{left: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  25%{left: -680px; opacity: 0;}
  34%{left: -680px; opacity: 0;}
  43%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
  52%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
  61%{left: 0;opacity: 1;}
  70%{left: 0;opacity: 1;}
  79%{left: -680px;opacity: 0;}
  88%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
  97%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
  100%{left: 0px;opacity: 0;}
}

@keyframes Anim {
  4%{left: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  16%{left: 0px;opacity: 1;}
  25%{left: -680px; opacity: 0;}
  34%{left: -680px; opacity: 0;}
  43%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
  52%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
  61%{left: 0;opacity: 1;}
  70%{left: 0;opacity: 1;}
  79%{left: -680px;opacity: 0;}
  88%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
  97%{left: 680px;opacity: 0;}
  100%{left: 0px;opacity: 0;}
}


div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: tomato;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```