# Перемещение слайдов js

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно сделать перемещение слайдов слева направо. Пробовал так:

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.sliders .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 3000);


function nextSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide + 1);
}

function previousSlide() {
  goToSlide(currentSlide - 1);
}

function goToSlide(n) {
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
  currentSlide = (n + slides.length) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}

var next = document.getElementById('next');
var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

next.onclick = function() {
  nextSlide();
  clearInterval(slideInterval);

}
previous.onclick = function() {
  previousSlide();
  clearInterval(slideInterval);
};
```

```css
.sliders {
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 45px
}

.slide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.showing {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in
}
```

```html
<div class="sliders">
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000" style="width:100%;height: 100%;border-radius: 5px"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/ff00ff" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;border-radius: 5px"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00fc00/ccff00" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;border-radius: 5px"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ccff00/00fc00" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;border-radius: 5px"></div>

  <button class="controls" id="previous">previous</button>
  <button class="controls" id="next">next</button>
</div>
```

Может в стилях ошибся?

Comment: А где у вас код, отвечающий за перемещение?

Comment: Ни в стилях ни в `js` перемещения нет... Только  `opacity`

Comment: Пробовал opacity заменить на transform, не получилось, transition: left 500ms linear;

Comment: Возможно ли сделать такое перемещение на css?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/574419/178988

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/703654/178988

Comment: Хотелось бы конкретно на моем примере, те варианты не походят, так как у меня нету фиксированной ширины контейнера с слайдерами

Comment: @ilyaaa521, вообще-то она там не нужна.

Comment: Вообще-то я не умничать в коментах просил, а подсказать как правильно сделать конкретно в моем случае.